# Customize QType for shorten path

Tags: querydsl

I'd would like to customizing a QType/Query to shorten a relationship.

```
public class Foo {
   private FooBar fooBar;
}

public class FooBar{
   private Bar bar;
}

public class Bar{
   private String name;
}
```

Currently the search is always foo.fooBar.bar.name. I would like to specify a shortened path so that foo.bar.name is possible directly. Is it possible to customize the relationship directly in the QFoo?

Build step

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Note:
With QueryEntity in another package it works fine together with the Eclipse Linkplugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use delegate methods for this (https://querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.4.0/reference/html_single/#d0e2479).

They work as follows:

In `Foo`, declare a delegate method:

```java
@QueryDelegate(Foo.class)
public static StringPath name(QFoo foo) {
    return foo.bar.name;
}
```

Now `QFoo` will be generated with a `name()` method that generates the `foo.bar.name` path.

Comment: Now I get a problem when building (maven) models because the Q classes are not there yet.
Processing failed: 
[ERROR] Note: Hibernate JPA 2 Static-Metamodel Generator 5.4.6.Final

Foo.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]    public static StringPath name( final QFoo ) {
[ERROR]                                         ^
[ERROR]   symbol:   class QFoo

Comment: Try putting the query delegate method in a different class file in the same package.

Comment: Putting it in the same class as `Foo` should be possible, but does require a specific compilation set up.  I suppose you're using the legacy Maven plugin for APT processing?

Comment: Did try both in a own class FooExstension

@QueryEntity
public class FooExtension{
   @QueryDelegate( Foo.class )
   public static StringPath name( final QFoo foo) {
      return foo.bar.name;
   }
}

Comment: Try removing the `apt-maven-plugin` plugin and add the following dependency instead: 
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <classifier>jpa</classifier>
</dependency>. Note the classifier specifically.

Comment: Ok let me check.

Comment: Do I have to add the dependency in the maven compile plugin. Same error message without apt plugin, now the eclipselink-maven-plugin is the problem. Maybe i have to put the exension class in antoher package, right?

Comment: Nice with another package and the apt plugin it works fine :)